# Laravel 5.2 - Selecting only articles that has comments

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I built a commenting system, and I'm working on a page that shows all the comments that are waiting for approval.

The relationship:

Article.php

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleComment');
}
```

ArticleComment.php

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}
```

Now, I want to select only the articles that have comments that are waiting for approval (`status` column on `article_comments` table equals `0`).

Any easy way of doing it? (Of course I can get all articles and check on each one if it has comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer will work but you asked for an easy (also re-usable) approach to use so I would suggest to create a `scope` method in your `ArticleComment` model using something like the following:

In your `Article` model:

```
use App\ArticleComment;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {

    // Relation for comments
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleComment::class);
    }

    // Relation for pending comments
    public function pendingComments()
    {
        return $this->comments()->pending();
    }
}
```

In your `ArticleComment` model:

```
// Query scope for pending comments
public function scopePending($query)
{
    $query->whereStatus(0);
}
```

So, you can use something like this:

```
$posts = Post::has('pendingComments')->get();
```

Also, you may chain `with` like:

```
$posts = Post::has('pendingComments')->with('pendingComments')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$articles = Article::whereHas('comments', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 0);
})->get();
```

Comment: Make sure to add `->get()` at the end